# copiar archivos a otra carpeta con php

Tags: php, archivo

tengo esta funcion

```
 $srcfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\*.*';
 $dstfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-copiadas\*.*';
 mkdir(dirname($dstfile), 0777, true); copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

al ejecutar el php necesito copiar todos los archivos del directorio

C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\    ==>    C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-copiadas\

Condiciones:

1. la carpeta destino C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-copiadas\ siempre estará vacía
2. La carpeta origen C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\ siempre tiene imagenes
3. Nunca se duplicaran por que antes de copiar se borran con: la funcion: array_map('unlink', glob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema con tu código es que php no reconoce el `*.*` como lo hace windows, por tanto lo que debes hacer es recorrer el directorio donde estan las imagenes a copiar y por cada archivo que encuentre copiarlo en el directorio nuevo.

```
$from = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\imagenes';
$to = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-copiadas';

//Abro el directorio que voy a leer
$dir = opendir($from);

//Recorro el directorio para leer los archivos que tiene
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
    //Leo todos los archivos excepto . y ..
    if(strpos($file, '.') !== 0){
        //Copio el archivo manteniendo el mismo nombre en la nueva carpeta
        copy($from.'/'.$file, $to.'/'.$file);
    }
}
```

**OJO** según lei la carpeta origen solo tiene archivos, si estos estan dentro de varias carpetas, hay que modificar un poco el código para hacerlo recursivo.

**OTRA VARIANTE** sería usar el comando de windows para copiar archivos, con este si puedes usar las máscaras como *.*

```
$from = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\copy\images\*.*';
$to = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\copy\copy-images';
//Ejecuto el comando para copiar los archivos de la carpeta from a to
exec('copy "'.$from.'" "'.$to.'"');
```

**ESPERO QUE ESTO PUEDA RESOLVER TU PROBLEMA**

Comment: Lo edite y le puse otra variante

Answer (score 0):

Me funcionó la variante, pero fue necesario eliminar las comillas y le agregué al final `/Y` para que sobre escriba los archivos sin preguntar:

```
$from = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\copy\images\*.*';
$to = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\copy\copy-images';
//Ejecuto el comando para copiar los archivos de la carpeta from a to
exec('copy '.$from.' '.$to.' /Y');
```